# Is an array and a List the same thing in Dart?

Tags: dart

I read the following quote in [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour):

> Perhaps the most common collection in nearly every programming
> language is the array, or ordered group of objects. In Dart, arrays
> are List objects, so most people just call them lists.

Does that mean the following two statements are the same?:

```
var names = ["John", "Robert", "James"];

List<String> names = ["John", "Robert", "James"];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Dart `List` type is what most other languages call "arrays" or "vectors".  That is, it is a data structure that stores elements contiguously to provide O(1) random access.

Dart uses `[` and `]` to create `List` *literals*.

> Does that mean the following two statements are the same?:
>
> ```
> var names = ["John", "Robert", "James"];
>
> List<String> names = ["John", "Robert", "James"];
> ```

Yes, they are the same thing.  DartPad or a Dart-aware IDE will let you inspect the static types of variables to show you that.